# How are initial articles alphabetized in Spanish?

Tags: alfabeto

In English, it is suggested that any initial "a, an, the" be ignored when alphabetizing a list (of titles, for instance).  Thus, the correct alphabetical order of (1) A Zebra, (2) An Elephant, and (3) The Cow is supposed to be:

```
The Cow
An Elephant
A Zebra.
```

Is there a similar rule for alphabetizing in Spanish, wherein leading articles (or any other leading words) should be ignored?  What would be the correct alphabetical order of (a) un bebé, (b) una bebé, (c) los dedos, (d) la familia, y (d) el policia?

Thanks!

Comment: @Lambie assume that the list is a list of book tittles that you need to alphabetize.  Which order do you put them in?  And I never suggested that you would drop the articles, merely that you would ignore them when alphabetizing your list.

Comment: Generally, books are listed by author, not title.

Comment: @Lambie Less humorously: many of the surviving libraries of this very day still file their fiction books by author.  But if the same author happens to write several books (which are not part of a series) they are secondarily filed by the Title of a Book.  And Microsoft's version of alphabetical order (which takes into account leading articles), is not the exclusive, nor the traditional, or even the correct alphabetical ordering, despite the fact that it has become almost universal.

Comment: Yes, then, you ignore the articles. But in writing, you tell the reader you are doing so. Whereas in a library, you would not.

Comment: I have answered the question. But here's the answer from Spain, from a library: https://www.bibliopos.es/ejercicio-de-alfabetizacion-catalogo-de-titulos-autores/ Without articles and so forth.

Comment: @Lambie Not from a library, but from a page that helps people preparing exams to work at a library. This means that they use the official criteria for all public libraries in Spain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikilengua del español](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ordenaci%C3%B3n_alfab%C3%A9tica), they can be ordered in both ways, either by considering the initial articles or by putting them at the end.

Thus, you can opt for **otros, Los** or **Los otros**, which would go on the letter "O" or on the letter "L", respectively.

According to the [guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c4KPYDaPjnW_SVl4_MpXLt_xQ6FFyB_h/view) linked by @[Lambie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182), which corresponds to a transcription of the cataloguing rules of the Biblioteca Nacional de España, articles are not considered and are added at the end.

> **9.2.11** The main entries whose access point is the title, will be sorted taking into account that the first sorting field is the complete title from the first highlighted word.
>
> **Contabilidad** de empresas
> **Contabilidad** para dirección
> **Contabilidad** y administración pública
> Corrons Prieto, Luis
> **Curs** bàsic de formació del comerciant
> **Curso** de economía de la mediana empresa
> Los **Directores** de grandes empresas españolas ante el cambio social
> The **Directory** of british importers
> The **Directory** of Church of England social services
> El **Greco**
> La **Innovación** industrial
> Kolb, David A.
> **Manual** de gestión personal
> Schmitt, Alfred
> O **Seculo XIX** em Portugal

Another [source](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/ordenacion-de-apellidos-2023/) mentions the following rule:

> in Spanish nouns it is customary to postpone the particles if there is
> a preposition and not to postpone the article if there is no
> preposition:
>
> **La Rosa**, Gerardo
>
> **Olmo**, Antonio del
>
> The order is the one that corresponds to this form (La Rosa precedes
> Olmo).

---

Según la [Wikilengua del español](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ordenaci%C3%B3n_alfab%C3%A9tica), pueden ordenarse de ambas maneras, tanto considerando los artículos iniciales como poniéndolos al final.

> Así, puede optarse por **otros, Los** o por **Los otros**, que irían en la
> letra o y en la ele, respectivamente.

Según la [guía enlazada](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c4KPYDaPjnW_SVl4_MpXLt_xQ6FFyB_h/view) por @[Lambie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182) que corresponde a una transcripción de las reglas de Catalogación la Biblioteca Nacional de España, no se consideran y se agregan al final.

> **9.2.11** Los asientos principales cuyo punto de acceso es el título, se ordenarán teniendo en cuenta que el primer campo de ordenación es el título completo a partir de la primera palabra destacada.
>
> **Contabilidad** de empresas
> **Contabilidad** para dirección
> **Contabilidad** y administración pública
> Corrons Prieto, Luis
> **Curs** bàsic de formació del comerciant
> **Curso** de economía de la mediana empresa
> Los **Directores** de grandes empresas españolas ante el cambio social
> The **Directory** of british importers
> The **Directory** of Church of England social services
> El **Greco**
> La **Innovación** industrial
> Kolb, David A.
> **Manual** de gestión personal
> Schmitt, Alfred
> O **Seculo XIX** em Portugal

Otra [fuente](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/ordenacion-de-apellidos-2023/) sugiere la siguiente regla:

> en nombres españoles se acostumbra a posponer las partículas si hay
> una preposición y a no posponer el artículo si no va con preposición:
>
> **La Rosa**, Gerardo
>
> **Olmo**, Antonio del
>
> La ordenación es la que corresponde a esta forma (La Rosa precede a
> Olmo).